# Need to provide complete chain of certificate for open ssl

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I had installed SSL certs one one of my cloud server by following this:

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-an-ssl-certificate-on-apache

I am running jetpack plugin on my wordpress blog. The jetpack plugin is not getting connected to wordpress. I have talked with the Jetpack support guys and they say this:

**Support Reply**

"The problem is that OpenSSL doesn't recognize your certificate's Certificate Authority's certificate. The that URL works in browsers is because most modern browsers allow for certificate discovery by reading the "Authority Information Access" metadata from the certificate, which contains a URL from which the browser can download the CA's certificate. OpenSSL does not.

The best solution is if you can configure your webserver to supply the entire SSL certificate chain, rather than just your own certificate. That's what we do on WordPress.com. Sending the entire chain will also make your sites more compatible with older (and I believe some mobile) browsers."

Can any one describe me how can I install or provide entire certificate chain???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These pages might help with setting up a CA and then creating a certificate: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL#SSL_Certificates
https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html